# How to exit when viewing python help like help(os.listdir)

Tags: python

when the help window pops up, what are the basic commands (mac os) to page up/down, end of document and **exiting** the help screen?

I just had to close my terminal as I couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You are probably in [`less`](http://www.gnu.org/software/less/) (this is configurable through the `PAGER` environment variable, but you probably haven't changed that). Press <kbd>h</kbd> for help and <kbd>q</kbd> to quit.

Comment: The OP stated he was in the help system. Pressing h within the help system brings up help on less.

Answer (score 3):

Other options to exit the help screen would be to type any one of the following(as described in the help section)
q,:q,Q,:Q and ZZ
.These can be seen when you press 'h' once you are on the help screen

Answer (score 1):

Just press the “q” key to quit out of a help() page generated in the python REPL. Yes, it is that easy, simply pressing “q” will exit out of the help screen properly.

You can move up and down with the arrow keys and press q to quit viewing the help page, similar to a UNIX man page.

Answer (score 0):

In addition  to what @Tanuj mentioned, you might need press enter to exit the help prompt after typing the above commands. Unlike how you exit a manual in linux by simply typing q

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32110325)